# How can I use a line in the header of a CSV file as the index in a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a .csv file with 4 lines in the header. One of them is the column names, and I've gotten that imported correctly, along with the rest of the data.

One of the lines in the header tells me the index values with a start value, a stop value and a step size. I can't figure out how to read that information and turn it into the index values for the dataframe.

The header looks like this:

```
Title
date time
index_start value, index_stop value, index_step, #, units
col1, col2, col3, col4
data, data, data, data
data, data ,data ,data
..., ..., ..., ..
```

Comment: This can be done with some file manipulation, but I don't think there's a native `pandas` way to read this file directly.

Answer (score 0):

You could read the file to get the index values, then use the `header` argument in `pd.DataFrame.from_csv()` to skip the first few lines. Finally create a new index with a few commands.

Here's an example.

Suppose the file was:

```
Title
date time
index_start 10, index_stop 30, index_step 10, #, units
col1, col2, col3, col4
1, a, data, data
2, b, data, data
3, c, data, data
```

**Step 1**: Read the file and get the index parameters.

```
filename = 'path/to/file'
index_start, index_stop, index_step = None, None, None
with open(filename, 'r') as f:
    title = f.readline().strip()  # read first line for title
    date, time = f.readline().strip().split()  # split line 2 on whitespace

    # first read line 3 and split on commas
    index_start, index_stop, index_step, _, _ = f.readline().strip().split(',')

    # split on whitespace and convert to int
    index_start = int(index_start.split()[1])
    index_stop = int(index_stop.split()[1])
    index_step = int(index_step.split()[1])
```

This works for my example file, but these commands would have to be modified for your specific file format since it was unclear from your question.

```
>>> print(index_start, index_stop, index_step)
(10, 30, 10)
```

**Step 2**: Read the file into a dataframe, skipping the first 3 lines.

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_csv(filename, header=3, index_col=None)
```

**Step 3**: Create your index as a new column and then use `set_index()` to make this the index.

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_csv(filename, header=3, index_col=None)
df['new_index'] = range(index_start, index_stop+index_step, index_step)
df = df.set_index('new_index')
df.index.name = None
```

**Final Output**:

```
    col1  col2   col3   col4
10     1     a   data   data
20     2     b   data   data
30     3     c   data   data
```